# Proving the inclusion exclusion principle from the definition of the cardinality

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, inclusion-exclusion

I want to prove the inclusion exclusion principle: 
    $|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A\cap B|$ where $A$ and $B$ are finite sets.

I proved the addition rule by contructing a bijection to a subset of the natural numbers and want to do the same here... Can you give me a hint, I don't want a full solution :)

Comment: Write $A$ as the disjoint union of two sets, $A\cap B$ and $A\setminus B$. Do the same for $B$. Now analyze which of these parts make up $A\cup B$.